# Export certificate from MAC KeyChain access and create keystore,truststore

Tags: java, macos, security, ssl

Thanks in advance , Can any one explain how to export a certificate from MAC KeyChain access and create keystore , truststore.

I tried the following steps but it failed.

- TLS certificate has been created in Apple keychain access .
- Then i exported the certificate and public key from keychain access as Certificate.p12 and Key.p12 with corresponding password.

And followed the below steps to generate keystore , truststore.

- convert the private key file from PKCS#12 format to PEM format:
  $ openssl pkcs12 -in Key.p12 -out Key.pem
- when prompt type the related password (P1):
  Enter Import Password:
  MAC verified OK
- choose a password for the new file (Key.pem)
  Enter PEM pass phrase:
  Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
- convert the certificate file from PKCS#12 format to PEM format:
  $ openssl pkcs12 -in Certificate.p12 -out Certificate.pem
- when prompt type the related password (P2):
  Enter Import Password:
  MAC verified OK
- choose a password for the new file (Certificate.pem)
  Enter PEM pass phrase:
  Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
  openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in Key.pem -inform PEM -out Key.der -outform DER
  openssl x509 -in Certificate.pem -inform PEM -out Certificate.der -outform DER

Ref link of ImportKey.java: [Imortkey.java|http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html]

user@host:~$ java ImportKey Key.der Certificate.der 
Using keystore-file : /home/user/keystore.ImportKey
One certificate, no chain.
Key and certificate stored.
Alias:vuiis Password:secret

cp keystore.ImportKey keystore.jks

keytool -export -file keystore.cert -keystore keystore.jks -alias vuiis
keytool -import -file keystore.cert -keystore trust.jks -alias vuiis

Finally i used keystore.jks as keystore and trust.jks as keytrust. But the connection was not successful.

My requirement is to establish TLS Connection between OSIRIX(MAC Keychain access) and DCM4CHEE (java keystore , truststore )

Any one can explain what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -trustcacerts switch to your import for your truststore.